# React build vs (?) Webpack?

Tags: javascript, front-end, react, webpack

Estou fazendo um curso de React. Tenho a compreensão do que o React é, e qual problema ele resolve.

Contudo quando eu coloco no CMD "create-react-app x" ele mostra alguns outros comandos que posso usar neste projeto entre eles o "npm run build" o que teoricamente compila o projeto para sua versão de distribuição.

Enquanto em outro video o instrutor diz para usar o webpack para gerar esta build?

Posso estar falando besteira sobre o "vs" no titulo da pergunta, mas qual a diferença entre ambos? Posso usar tanto um quanto outro? Ou os dois usam o mesmo sistema para compilar?

Valeu abraços.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, qual o propósito do `create-react-app`? Na documentação:

> Create React apps with no build configuration.

Antes da existência do `create-react-app`, você deveria implementar seu próprio "sistema" de build. Podia ser webpack, gulp, ou até grunt.

Isso significava que você buildava todo seu projeto, bonitinho, com JSX, ES6, Sass, e era obrigado a utilizar uma dessas ferramentas e definir o que elas fariam. Transpilar, minificar, lintar e tudo o mais que você quisesse. Era um trabalho bem grande, que envolvia vários scripts e muita pesquisa no google, barreira de entrada bem complicada para quem quisesse começar a programar com React.

O `create-react-app` veio pra facilitar toda essa parte de configuração e build, e te deixar focar só no seu projeto. **Por trás dos panos ele utiliza o webpack**, com scripts até que bem grandes, pra fazer toda essa parte chata que antes você tinha que fazer na mão.

Eu recomendo você criar um projeto novo, com o `create-react-app` e executar o comando `npm run eject`. O que esse comando faz é "desocultar" tudo que ele oculta de configuração. Aí você vai ver o arquivo de config do webpack, ver os scripts e tudo mais. **Só cuidado que uma vez o projeto "ejected", não tem como voltar atrás.**